# Mocking API using selenium(java) and fiddler

Tags: java, api, selenium, automation, fiddler

I want to write automation script using selenium(java) using UI only. So, I want to mock the APIs used, using fiddler, i.e., I want to modify request and response  of a URL in scripts.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your actual question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.